# How to specify name for a dropdownlist asp.net mvc in hard coded scenario?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor, selectlistitem

This is in my action method:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> Courses = new List<SelectListItem>();
            Courses.Add(new SelectListItem{Text="Math", Value = "1"});
            Courses.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Science", Value = "2"});
            Courses.Add(new SelectListItem{Text="Literature", Value = "3"});
            ViewBag.hardCodedList = Courses;
            return View();
        }
```

I know I can do this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("hardCodedList", "SelectList")
```

But the dropdownlist name would also be hardCodedList.

Here I want to specify the list name as CourseList,and I try this is in my Index view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CourseList", ViewBag.hardCodedList, "SelectList")
```

but it doesn't work:

I also know I can specify name of the list if I pass an anonymous list like this:

```
  @Html.DropDownList("CourseList", new List<SelectListItem>
        {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "IT", Value = "1", Selected=true},
        new SelectListItem { Text = "HR", Value = "2"},
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Finance", Value = "3"}
        }, "SelectList")
```

But here I want to keep the list in my action method, not in the view. How can I specify name in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewbag is dynamic so try casting it.

change

```
@Html.DropDownList("CourseList", ViewBag.hardCodedList, "SelectList")
```

to something like:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CourseList", ViewBag.hardCodedList as List<SelectListItem>, "SelectList")
```